# Duplicating WCF services when using WCF and MSMQ

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq

I have a project in which I am planning to the WCF/MSMQ integration. But there is something that is confusing me:
In this integration, I define a service and a queue with with the same name as the service. When the service is called, the message is placed on the queue until the service is ready to consume it.
My question is: am I able to replicate this service in different machines, but still consume the messages from the original queue?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this and is used in high availability solutions. For example: Imagine you have 5 WCF services on different servers pointing to the same msmq on a different machine. Now if you had 7 messages in the queue already and the services start back up the messages are handled by only one of the wcf service instances.

As new messages come in they are actually divided among the wcf services.